# Disable vertical quote bar?

Tags: mail.app, python

Mail.app's vertical bar formatting of replies is usually useful.  I have one annoying case that comes up very frequently for me that I have been trying to find a solution for.  I am a Python programmer and am on mailing lists that include Python code snippets regularly.  The problem is that Python command line application uses `>>>` as its prompt.  This triggers the quote formatting behavior incorrectly.  For example, the following email snippet is formatted incorrectly (IMO).

```
The code is useless, just to show the idea

>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a.sort()
>>> c = max(a) + 1

I would be very happy to have

>>> [1,2,3].append(4)::sort()::max() +1
```

The result in Mail.app is:

[image: python code example]

Does anyone know of a way to disable the quote bar behavior altogether?

*source email: [https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2019-February/055374.html](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2019-February/055374.html_)*

Answer (score 1):

You could turn off quoting. 
mail > preferences 
see responding section.

[image]

Comment: I did try this hoping that it would work, but it controls whether the message is copied when sending a reply.  My problem is that I am receiving messages from a mailing list where `>>>` is the python prompt instead of three levels of quoting.  I need a similar setting in *Viewing*.